# How to lock the fonts of a PowerPoint file?

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, embedded-fonts

Is it possible to lock the fonts of a PowerPoint file?

I mean if there is any way to set a specific font to be the only one to be used in the document, which is a PowerPoint template, so anyone who uses it it'll have only one font to choose.

Thanks!

Comment: Slideshow already created? Deny or revoke write access to the file...

Comment: @AthomSfere I'll edit my question to make it more clear

Comment: I suppose you wish to allow users to make changes, but you want them to use only the specific fonts which you want.

Comment: @Firee exactly! I'm just wondering if is possible, I did some research and found nothing about it

Comment: @elunicotomas The functionality is available for Word, but not for Powerpoint. Guess you'll have to use a macro.

Comment: @Firee yep, i think i'll have to figure it out with a macro, thanks anyway!